# ANTLR 4 target language generation

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to build a translator using ANTLR 4 and Java, so far I am done with the grammar and the Parse tree generation. I used **ArrayLists** with the **ANTLR Listener** to read each node from the Parse Tree.

My problem is that, I don't know what is the sequence to generate the target language.

Could any one please, provide me with step-by-step guidance to generate the target language, or any source code the shows these steps.

Thank you,

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table - that's something you have to do on your own, ANTLR won't know the semantics of your grammar.

Comment: you need to apply rules to generate the language that you want, you can specify to antlr in which language you will process all your tokens and rules, but the generation of what you are trying to target needs to be performed by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language Implementation Patterns book provides step-by-step guidance to code generation techniques under ANTLR 4 and sample code in Java.